# About transformers: very little primary current if the secondary is unloaded

Tags: transformer

This extract is from [a popular electronics book](https://artofelectronics.net):

> ... a transformer of turns ratio \$n\$ increases the impedance by \$n^2\$. **There is very little primary current if the secondary is unloaded.**

I'm thinking about the emboldened part. Please see if the following argument is correct: If the secondary is unloaded, its current is zero, so the secondary can be neglected (as if it doesn't exist at all), and the transformer can be modeled as a single inductor with inductance of \$L\$. And according to the relations

$$X_L=2\pi\nu L$$

and

$$V=X_L I,$$

\$L\$ must be large if primary current is 'very little'.

Comment: Look up transformer equivalent model. The secondary current will dominate the primary so much you can offer omit the magnitizing current. At very light load however, it’s a significant portion of the primary current.

Comment: [Related question and answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230404/how-does-the-secondary-coil-of-a-transformer-affect-the-primary-coil-how-is-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct. A transformer always has a "magnetizing current" (reactive) that is determined by its own inductance, whether or not it is loaded.

Loading the secondary imposes a second "resistive" (in-phase) current that varies with the load.

It sounds as if the book you quoted is referring to this in-phase component only, and ignoring the magnetizing current.

Comment: Magnetizing currents can be 10% with 10% load regulation on small transformers such that no load current is 10% reactive and Vout drops 10% to rated voltage, down to <1% on large grid XFMR’s